# I think my "list" question was not too broad and should be reopened

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

So I didn't know about the whole [list thing](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1532/11471) when I asked [What are all the different species of intelligent beings that God has created?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/30772/11471)... I've now read some meta posts on it and I understand why we don't want list questions as they can be too broad and be looking for responses and not answers.

Having said that, I don't think my question falls under that category at all. I was asking for a list from scripture, not an ever-changing, opinion based list from pop culture. I think some people saw the word "list" in my question and impulsively sprinted to the flag button without giving it some thought :P. Check out the [the first answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/30775/11471) to my question and you can see how he was giving me just the answer I was looking for. I didn't accept it right away because I was hoping for at least 1 other answer, just to compare.

I've since removed any references to lists in my question but I think it might have been too late: group think sunk the ship and got the question put on hold.

So I'm just requesting that my question be considered for reopening and that a mod reopens it, or something.

Answer (score 3):

Only one of the four close votes on your question mentioned the list aspect.

But you're right, there isn't an issue with lists here, that *particular* close vote was cast in error.

The issue here (and why I cast the close vote), is that your criteria is too loose. What exactly is the definition of intelligence that you're using? What counts?

More importantly, what are you hoping to *learn* from this question? What does it add to your knowledge? Help us understand why this is important for you to learn.

Comment: "*More importantly, what are you hoping to learn from this question? What does it add to your knowledge? Help us understand why this is important for you to learn*." Why exactly does it matter? I don't mean to sound rude. Wanting to know why I ask a question seems out of scope for this site. I ask the question because I want to know the answer. Was there a greater expectation?

Comment: @LCIII see: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask. Namely: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." Asking someone to explain at least what prompted the question seems within the spirit of that...

Comment: I agree with @LCIII and have always thought that bit in the "dont ask" section of the help center was misguided and confusing. I don't see how giving reason for the question actually changes the question. It seems that the idea behind that is to prompt askers to be through, a problem on SO, but not so much here. If anything, we get too many details that don't help answerers.

Answer (score 2):

The question is plenty answerable. I voted to reopen. The topic has a wide abundance of literature that cover what you are asking for. I don't see the problem. [The current best answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/30775/3961) is pretty good too.

It doesn't fall into [one of the typical six types](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3409/types-of-questions-or-template-questions-that-the-community-generally-finds-ac), but there are quite a few questions that don't. Questions in the other category are often the most interesting. You just have to word them very carefully and specifically so that the community doesn't think they are off-topic.