# Are questions that ask for answers from various theological contexts always overly broad?

Tags: discussion

Are questions that ask for answers from various theological contexts always overly broad and to be flagged?
For example,

> How do the various traditions today celebrate Christmas?

Or

> How do non-Predestinationalists understand Matt 2:15 as not referring to predestined, divine guidance?
>
> > Out of Egypt I called my son?

ON SECOND THOUGHT, I wonder if this second example would be better on the Christian Exegesis stackexchange.

> What are the various ways of interpreting Matt 2:15?

Yes, this is asking for a list, but I believe it is quite a small list, or perhaps better:

> Does Matt 2:15 necessarily  indicate that God controls all things or at least that He controlled the steps that made Jesus flee to Egypt and return?

Answer (score 4):

No. Sometimes Overview questions are allowed, but we expect such question to explicitly state that they are looking for an overview of all perspectives. Even then not all overview questions are helpful, and if I thought that there were more than a handful of perspectives I'd still vote to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are too broad. Simply put, there are so many variations within Christianity that such questions can only be answered partially.

Such questions are sometimes referred to as "list questions" because they ask for a list of various answers from differing theological contexts.  Whether they are or are not on topic has already been answered at [How should we handle “List Questions”](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1532/how-should-we-handle-list-questions)

Unless you're able to somehow limit the desired answers to a manageable number of possible views, there's really no way to answer such questions and avoid that issue.

Comment: what about overview questions? That is the exception right?